# How to Notify Print status of a pdf document after print?

Tags: c#, pdf, printing, system.drawing, system.printing

Is  it possible to print a PDF document using `'System.Printing'` Namespace? How does it differ from `System.Drawing.Printing'`? I want to print a document and check whether it is printed or not! Presently i use a process to print pdf as

```
            var fileName = filepath;
            ProcessStartInfo psInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            psInfo.Arguments = "HP LaserJet P1505n";
            psInfo.FileName = fileName;
            psInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            psInfo.Verb = "print";
            psInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            psInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            process = Process.Start(psInfo);
```

Here i cannot determine page printed or not!

How can i accomplish this? It is possible to check status of printer using Win32_Printer with  `System.Management` namespace but not "printing" status

Comment: This is a fairly pointless pursuit, no kind of software is going to tell you that the pages that come out of the printer are readable.  Use your code as-is, if there's a problem with the printout then it is somebody else's problem.

Comment: Lol!.. what i meant is "Is the page this process sends to printer, is printed or not".Simple.